# How to test if a computer has internet access?

Tags: delphi, networking, database-connection, delphi-7

I have a delphi program that is used in multiple stores. These stores all connect to an online mysql database. On the application start up, the program connects to the database. The program was freezing when the computer was not connected to the internet. I found this below procedure that tests if the computer is connected to the internet:

```
public
function IsConnectedToInternet: Boolean;   

const
  INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM = 1;
  INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN = 2;
  INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY = 4;
  INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM_BUSY = 8; 

implementation

function InternetGetConnectedState(lpdwFlags: LPDWORD;
dwReserved: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'WININET.DLL';

function TForm1.IsConnectedToInternet: Boolean;
var
dwConnectionTypes: Integer;
begin
  try
    dwConnectionTypes := INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM +
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN +
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY;

    if InternetGetConnectedState(@dwConnectionTypes, 0) then
      Result := true
    else
      Result := false;
  except
    Result := false;
  end;
end;

procedure Tform1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If IsConnectedToInternet then
    MysqlConnection.Connect;
end;
```

This works fine in testing if the computer is **connected** to the **wifi** etc.. But it does not test if this connection has internet access. Example if the computer is connected to a wifi which has a limit of 10gb and when that 10gb is used up, the computer will still be connected to the wifi but will not have internet access.

In this case the above function will give a result of **true** making the program try to connect and this will make the program freeze.

How do i resolve this error? Is there a procedure that tests if the computer has **internet access**?

Comment: Why bother checking? Just attempt to connect. If it works, then you're connected. If it fails, then you aren't.

Comment: Well the right thing to do is to keep the db connection code off your gui thread. And make your program robust to connection failures. If you really want to stop your program freezing you will not put the db code on the GUI thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you suggesting i create a separate unit that connects to the server?

Comment: No. I'm telling you that the only way for your program to remain responsive is for you to stop running the db code in the main UI thread. Your db code will block the UI thread and stop it being able to service it's message queue.

Comment: View this link its a solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22404225/3177854][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22404225/3177854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way to check connectivity is to attempt to connect. Doing so can block the thread which attempts to connect. The logical conclusion then is that to stop the UI thread from being blocked, you must connect from a thread other than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your uses the unit "WinNet". With the function "InternetGetConnectedState" return a value for internet state and type. See below:

```
    function YourFunctionName : boolean;
  var
     origin : cardinal;
  begin
     result := InternetGetConnectedState(@origin,0);

     //connections origins by origin value
     //NO INTERNET CONNECTION              = 0;
     //INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM           = 1;
     //INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN             = 2;
     //INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY           = 4;
     //INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM_BUSY      = 8;
  end;
```

Comment: As the question explains: "In this case the above function will give a result of true making the program try to connect and this will make the program freeze.", so it is not helpful

Comment: To avoid freezing the main window, it is good that the function is implemented in a thread