# delphi check internet connection

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I need a working function for Delphi 2010 to check if there is Internet connection available.

I say working because so far I tried 4 different methods e.g. http://delphi.about.com/b/2005/04/22/how-to-check-for-internet-connection-using-delphi-code.htm but neither worked.

For example one method alway gave back that there was internet connection even when the cable was not in the pc, the other the opposite (it always said there was no connection).

```
     procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject) ;

      function FuncAvail(_dllname, _funcname: string;
                         var _p: pointer): boolean;
      {return True if _funcname exists in _dllname}
      var _lib: tHandle;
      begin
       Result := false;
       if LoadLibrary(PChar(_dllname)) = 0 then exit;
       _lib := GetModuleHandle(PChar(_dllname)) ;
       if _lib <> 0 then begin
        _p := GetProcAddress(_lib, PChar(_funcname)) ;
        if _p <> NIL then Result := true;
       end;
      end;

      {
      Call SHELL32.DLL for Win < Win98
      otherwise call URL.dll
      }
      {button code:}
      var
       InetIsOffline : function(dwFlags: DWORD):
                       BOOL; stdcall;
      begin
       if FuncAvail('URL.DLL', 'InetIsOffline',
                    @InetIsOffline) then
        if InetIsOffLine(0) = true
         then ShowMessage('Not connected')
         else ShowMessage('Connected!') ;
      end;
```

Comment: What EXACTLY did you try?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a code writing service, where you post your requirements and then say "Write me a function that is tested already. I'll stop back later to pick it up. Thanks.". We're glad to help answer specific questions about problems you're having with your code, but in order to do so you need to **post your code** and a description of the problem and ask a specific question first. If you need an on-demand code writer, hire a contractor or consultant. Good luck.

Comment: FYI http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/

Comment: Sorry I offended you. I thought that providing a valid link would make the reader click on it. I pasted the code in my original question, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add in your uses the unit "WinNet". With the function "InternetGetConnectedState" return a value for internet state and type. See below:

```
function YourFunctionName : boolean;
  var
     origin : cardinal;
  begin
     result := InternetGetConnectedState(@origin,0);

     //connections origins by origin value
     //NO INTERNET CONNECTION              = 0;
     //INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM           = 1;
     //INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN             = 2;
     //INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY           = 4;
     //INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM_BUSY      = 8;
  end;
```

**update** i newer Delphi versions add "wininet" as uses class.

Comment: Correct: Uses WinINet

Answer (score 17):

The only *reliable* method is to attempt to connect to a real server on the Internet somewhere and see if it succeeds or fails.  Don't use OS functions that rely on OS state information, because that data can easily get out of sync.

Comment: And we need to go deeper and examine the definition of "being connected to Internet".

Comment: What if i want to check only the LAN connection (cable disconnected)?

Comment: @tdiop look at the [Network List Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370803.aspx) API. But consider that many networks are wireless nowadays, there may not be a cable used

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `TIdHTTP` component:

```
function TMainF.isInternetConnection: Boolean;
begin
  try
    IdHTTP.Get('http://www.svtech.cz');
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      if not (E is EIdHTTPProtocolException) then begin
        Result := False;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: TIdHTTP could fail for many reasons, either socket related or HTTP related. You would have to analyze the raised exception to figure out why it failed. For instance, it makes sense to return false on a socket error, but not on an HTTP error since a connection was successful.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes, especially now, that most pages have moved to HTTPS and this snippet most likely will fail HTTPS "as is".

Comment: @ChrisS. Maybe, maybe not. `TIdHTTP` supports HTTPS, you just need an `SSLIOHandler` component assigned to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property. [`TIdHTTP` can create a default `SSLIOHandler` for you](https://www.indyproject.org/2014/12/22/new-https-functionality-for-tidhttp/), but it currently defaults to TLS 1.0 only, which websites are starting to move away from. To use TLS 1.1+, you would have to assign an `SSLIOHandler` manually.

Comment: I changed to 'http://www.svtech.czsdfsdfasdfasfdas', result still true